# Remove corrupted files in git when no changes present in local

Tags: git

I detected a problem where for example I have an image (happens to more than just one file) in my repo, but this file is corrupted.

If I fresh clone my repo, I see that this file is indeed corrupted and my system can't read it, but if I compile my project again (gulp), I see it generates a fine file, the problem is that git doesn't detect changes between the corrupted and the good file so I can't upload changes.

How could I remove the folder where my project compiles in a way that I can upload it again, without losing my commit history (or not loosing that much history)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, try and clone again after typing

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That will make sure your file does not have its eol characters changed automatically depending on your OS.

The OP confirms in the comments:

> I had a `.gitattributes` with a line `* text eol=lf`

That is too wide a selection, and you need to apply it only to the file you want, for instance:

```
*.cpp text eol=lf
```

Comment: Yeah, I have core.autocrlf already in false, but the problem keeps going -.-

Comment: @codiaf what `git status` and `git diff` return after a fresh clone?

Comment: hummm, a fresh clone shows several modified files with git status, and git diff shows a lot of ```warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/images/icon-all.png.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.```

Comment: @codiaf do you have any `.gitattributes` in your repo? (with `core.eol` directives)

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, I had a .gitattributes with a line ```* text eol=lf```

Comment: @codiaf OK, I have amended the answer accordingly.