# How to properly push images in github repo?

Tags: git, image, github

I have a problem with images in my repo: after pushing them, Git shows them as:

[image: error]

And when you pull it again in your local repository, the image is empty or broken.
Does anybody faced with this issue?

Tried to push image as text file, same situation.
Size of images small(~100kb) & size about 800*600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Git config or `.gitattributes` for any setting that might modify automatically the content of your image when added to your repository.

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232007/6309), make sure git config `core.autocrlf` is set to false.

The goal is to make sure a local (and valid) image can be added/committed to your local repository, and then push, *without any change*.